# React Native easiest way to show logs in device

Tags: logging, react-native

Is there a trivial way to show logs in an react native app being a device disconnected from the mac/pc?

Answer (score 0):

How about saving console.log to state, and showing it in a Text field? I've done it before.

```js
this.state = { logMessages: [] }

//// Custom log message
let alllogs = this.state.logMessages;

alllogs.push('Custom Log message');
this.setState({logMessages: alllogs});


renderLogs(){
  let logs = this.state.logMessages;
  let content;
  logs.forEach((e)=>{
    content += <Text>{e}</Text>;
  });
  return content;
}
Render(){
  return(
    <View>{this.renderLogs()}</View>
  );
}
```

I haven't tested it, i just wrote it here, but it's just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the `Debug` build of your app on the device and you are on the same network simply enable `Remote debugging` by shaking your phone.

Otherwise you can use a third party service like `Hockeyapp`or `Bugsnag` (both are really good) that can simply being configured into your app that report in a really nice way all the `Javascript` and `Native` errors/crash

Answer (score 0):

I'm on OSX and when I need to view logs I just connect my device, and open the 'Console' app, which comes with OSX.

I can then find my iPhone and view logs. From there I filter logs with 'Process' being the app I am interested in.

For Android, different process, I use `react-native log-android | grep ' which was good enough for that I was interested in.